# Irreducibility of $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{96}+x^{97}+x^{98}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

The question I encounter is

> Determine whether the polynomial $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{96}+x^{97}+x^{98}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ or not

All the methods that I learnt (Eisenstein Criterion, Rational Root Theorem and reduce the polynomial to $\mathbb F_p$) fails. I have no idea towards the question.

Comment: Hint: It is $\frac{x^{99}-1}{x-1}$. But wait, isn't $x^{99}-1$ divisible by polynomials of higher degreen?

Comment: Hint: $x^{99}-1=(x-1)(x^{98}+x^{97}+...+x+1)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews higher degreen... is that bigger than nineteen?

Comment: So, in other words, I need to show $\frac{x^{99}-1}{x-1}$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here’s the secret that nobody is telling you: $X^{99}-1$ is the polynomial whose roots are the ninety-ninth roots of unity, of which one is $1$, so that $X-1$ divides $X^{99}-1$, with quotient your polynomial. But (moderately) advanced mathematics tells you that $X^n-1$ is the product of the “cyclotomic polynomials” $\Phi_d(X)$, where $d$ ranges through the divisors of $n$. $\Phi_d$ is the polynomial whose roots are the $d$-th roots of unity that aren’t $d'$-th roots of unity for any $d'<d$, so that $\Phi_1(X)=X-1$, $\Phi_2(X)=X+1$, and $\Phi_3(X)=X^2+X+1$. All the cyclotomic polynomials have their coefficients in $\Bbb Z$.

As a particular example of what I said above, we have:
$$
X^{99}-1=\Phi_1\Phi_3\Phi_9\Phi_{11}\Phi_{33}\Phi_{99}\,,
$$
and your polynomial is the above product with the factor $X-1=\Phi_1$ omitted. The factors that people have exhibited are $\Phi_3$, $\Phi_9$, and $\Phi_{11}$.

Comment: In my defense: my answer just popped into my head.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!!

Comment: Oops, the factor of degree eight that @WillJagy exhibited is rather $\Phi_3\cdot\Phi_9$.

Comment: This is much more sophisticated than necessary. All you need to know is that $x^n - 1$ divides $x^{nm} - 1$, and this is a completely elementary statement that doesn't require you to know anything about roots of unity. In particular, $x^3 - 1$ divides $x^{99} - 1$, as does $x^{11} - 1$, etc.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, of course it is. But it’s the sort of lovely mathematics that everybody should be exposed to.

Comment: This would be fine if anyone else had said the elementary thing already...

Answer (score 3):

Your polynomial is divisible by $1+x+x^2$. One can verify this in many ways, for example polynomial division. Or else divide into groups of $3$, the first being $1+x+x^2$, the second $x^3(1+x+x^2)$, and so on. Or else one can see that $e^{\pm 2\pi i/3}$ are roots.

Comment: How did you know to check for $1+x+x^2$?

Comment: @Ovi: Many ways. You can divide the terms into groups of $3$, each divisible by $1+x+x^2$. Or else we can think about $x^{99}-1$, which is divisible by $x^3-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For those keeping score at home: THIS JUST POPPED INTO MY HEAD. Multiply it out.

$$ (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{10})(1 + x^{11}  + x^{22} + \cdots  + x^{88}  )  $$

OR

$$ (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{8})(1 + x^{9}  + x^{18} + \cdots  + x^{90}  )  $$

Comment: How to conclude this?

Comment: $x^{99}-1 = (x^{11})^{9} - 1$. Now set $y = x^{11}.$ Then $y^{9}-1 = (y-1)( 1+y + y^{2} + \ldots + y^{8}).$ Then note that $(y-1) = (x-1)(  1+ x + x^{2} + x^{10}).$. Divide both sides of first equation by$ x-1$ and you get what Will did in the second example. The first is similar. This is a special case of what Lubin's answer shows ( but more along the elementary lines that Qiaochu hints at).